# Angular Primary and Named Route Navigation with RouterLink

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

After much pain, I got this to work:
`this.router.navigateByUrl('/live-chat(subnav:subnav)');`
But I cannot seem to reproduce that with a `[routerLink]=''` directive.

The goal is to navigate to a top level page and set the left side subnav to a specific component as well.

App Component Layout:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <router-outlet name="alerts"></router-outlet>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="content-container">
    <router-outlet name="subnav"></router-outlet>
    <div class="content-area">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Router Setup:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'live-chat', component: LiveChatComponent },
  { path: 'subnav', component: SubnavComponent, outlet: 'subnav' },
]),
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, namely navigating the "primary" / "un-named" router by referring to "primary":

```
<a class="nav-link nav-text" 
    [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['live-chat'], subnav: ['subnav'] } } ]">
    Live Chat</a>
<a class="nav-link nav-text"
    [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['contacts'], subnav: ['contacts-list'] } }]">
    Contacts</a>
```